# HTML document selection using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I use this javascript code to get the currently highlighted selection.

```
var selection = window.getSelection()
```

If the highlight is a section of text all within a `<div>`, how can I get the offset from the beginning of the `<div>` and the length of the highlight? (the length is not just the length of the text, it should be the actual length of the html code for that text)

Comment: Offset from the beginning of what?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the length of the selected HTML as follows:

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var sel, html = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var frag = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.appendChild(frag);
            html = el.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
    return html;
}

alert(getSelectionHtml().length);
```

Comment: so this code copies the selection into a new div, then counts the length of its innerHtml?

Comment: In non-IE browsers, yes, exactly.

Comment: what about the offset from the beginning of the parent element? thanks

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to rana's question, too.

Comment: Such an offset is unlikely to be useful and difficult to obtain. What's wrong with the offset you get from a Range obtained from the selection?